# Deux mots successifs précédés par l'article « du »

Tags: articles

> La covariance est un paramètre du bruit qui appartient au signal observé.

Quelle est la phrase correcte ?

> 1. la covariance du bruit du signal observé
> 2. la covariance de bruit du signal observé
> 3. la covariance du bruit de signal observé
> 4. la covariance de bruit de signal observé

Comment: La phrase d'origine n'a pas grand sens, difficile donc de la reformuler. Si c'est une traduction, quel est le texte d'origine ?  et sinon quel texte précède cette phrase ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il semble qu'un terme plus approprié pour caractériser la relation entre le signal et le bruit attenant serait « associé » ; la notion mathématique d'appartenance est totalement étrangère à ce concept physique et la notion générale aussi ; le TLFi porte la définition suivante qui aurait pu convenir mais qui est applicable aux chose abstraites, ce que le bruit n'est pas. De plus le bruit n'est pas une caratéristique du signal mais des impulsions électriques qui existent conjointement avec le signal.

> appartenir P. ext. [En parlant d'une chose abstr.] Être le propre de

« La covariance est un paramètre du bruit associé au signal observé. » serait plus exact il me semble. Selon ce point de vue il n'y a plus besoin de « de » ou « du ».

- La covariance du bruit associé au signal observé

Answer (score 1):

La première option est la bonne :

> La covariance du bruit du signal observé.

Answer (score 1):

Oui, on peut écrire Le X du Y du Z

À la condition évidente que X ∈ Y AND Y ∈ Z

C'est à dire ici que [covariance] ∈ [bruit] ET [bruit] ∈ [signal]

Comme on a toujours et partout distingué le *signal* du *bruit*, au point d'en faire des rapports... La seconde condition ne peut pas être valide => On ne peut pas écrire cela comme ça.

Nota : Préférer *de* ne changerait évidemment rien à ce problème lié à la compréhension de la phrase initiale.

Answer (score 0):

Votre phrase "La covariance est un paramètre du bruit qui appartient au signal observé" est une traduction un peu maladroite de  l'anglais. En effet un paramètre ne peut "appartenir" à un signal ; il faudrait dire
"La covariance est un paramètre du bruit qui dépend du signal observé"
ou bien
"La covariance est un paramètre du bruit qui dépend spécifiquement du signal observé".